# How can i animate images when my slide transitions to the next slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

These are the options that the plugin offers. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

I have 5 different slides. But each slide has two to three images inside the slide that should animate in different positions within the slide, how can i achieve this?
Or is there another jQuery Plugin that will allow you to do this?

**For example.**
I have one slide that has a car, a cloud and a sun. So when the user hovers or reaches this slide. The car will animate to the center and then the cloud and the sun will animate and position themselves after the car animates in.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a parallax slider. [Here](http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/) you can see an example.

Answer (score 1):

Parallax could be a potential solution, but I'd look more at the options that Cycle provides.

Take a look at this example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Toward the bottom it mentions before and after slide callbacks. So in theory, you could call a function that animates everything into place, then when the next slide comes in, call the next animation for the next slide (if there is one).

This could prove cumbersome if your slider is on a timer. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

Well you could do several things. You could make it so that when the mouse hovers over the image, it turns to a gif that animates itself.

```
.background:hover {
background-image: url('<filepath>/animate.gif');
}
```

Or you could do a jQuery event where when the button is clicked, or when the mouse hovers (a little bit trickier, in my opinion), each individual element (individual images layered on top, probably via z-index) would animate and slide over.

I would recommend the first option if you are using a jQuery plugin.

Comment: there are four slides & a animated gif would not help in my case. Thanks anyway